# Работа с виртуальной памятью С++

Tags: c++, структуры-данных, виртуальная-память

Как поместить элементы структуры данных (очередь, список, стек) в виртуальную память, которая выделяется с помощью Virtualalloc? С массивом вроде как разобрался, но внятной информации про структуры не повстречал.

Comment: Как угодно. Вся память выделяется через `VirtualAlloc`. Если делать это вручную, то через placement new.

Comment: То есть написать по типу [структура] = new (VirtualAlloc(....) )?

Comment: [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)

Comment: Virtualalloc вызывается два раза. Один раз MEM_RESERVED второй раз уже с зарезервированым адресом MEM_COMMIT. Память выделяется кратно 4096 и так же выравнена по границам 4к. Чистим - руцями.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помещение структуры в выделенную память VirtualAlloc C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805500/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-virtualalloc-c)