# Помещение структуры в выделенную память VirtualAlloc C++

Tags: c++, виртуальная-память

Здравствуйте, как после зарезервированния/выделения виртуальной памяти,(таким способом) использовать её.

```
VirtualAlloc(NULL, 1024*10, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)
```

По типу есть структура данных, как сделать чтобы элементы структуры находились в этой памяти?

Comment: memcpy уже пробовали?

Comment: нет, а так будет нормально работать?

Comment: Отлично будет структуру копировать в другую область памяти. И вообще все что угодно копировать будет!

Comment: понял, просто насколько я понял, что будет как бы 2 структуры в разных участках памяти.

Comment: А не все ли равно? Копируете, освобождаете источник и готово.

Answer (score 2):

Вы получаете некий указатель

```
void * ptr = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 1024*10, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

Что дальше вы будете делать с этим указателем - систему не интересует.

Вы можете привести его к указателю на Вашу структуру

```
mystruct * st = (mystruct *)ptr;
```

и далее работать с `st` как с обычным указателем.

Вы можете скопировать в него некоторые данные при помощи `memcpy`.

Вы можете разделить эту память между двумя структурами

```
mystruct1 * st1 = (mystruct1 *)ptr;
mystruct2 * st2 = (mystruct2 *)(ptr + size_of(mystruct1));
```

В общем - это обычная выделенная память

Comment: а если это готовая структура - очередь, стэк?

Comment: Как это "готовая"? VirtualAlloc заливает всю память нулями. Что там может быть готового?

Comment: имел в виду что создан стэк (очередь) и как тогда сделать что бы элементы хранились в памяти выделенной VirtualAlloc?

Comment: Тут важно что бы размер структуры не превышал размер выделеной памяти. Как посчитать - `sizeof(mystruct1)*elements`

Comment: Как сделать что б елементы хранились в памяти - вот `mystruct * st = (mystruct *)ptr;`